# Error loading the grails gwt module xml

Tags: gwt, grails, grails-plugin

I've installed the plugin from this article by Peter
http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/the-command-pattern-w....

While compile time its not able to find the module file which is
present in the plugin. Since there are no jar files for the module,
can you tell me what I'm missing here..

The stack trace is as follows:

```
 [java]    Loading inherited module 'grails.plugins.gwt.Grails'
 [java]       [ERROR] Unable to find 'grails/plugins/gwt/Grails.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to incl
```

ude a classpath entry for source?
     [java]    [ERROR] Line 12: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
     [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Satya, I've had similar problems with classpath errors working with other grails plugins.

I've found sometimes it's necessary to manually copy artifacts from (user-home directory)/.grails/(grails-version)/plugins/(plugin-name) into the lib/ directory inside my grails project.

In this case, you might try copying src/gwt (from the grails-gwt-0.5-SNAPSHOT.zip) into lib/gwt? or maybe try to copy it to match grails/plugins/gwt/Grails.gwt.xml?